# PHP Post Body Encoding Problems

Tags: php, http, post, encoding, arrays

I'm trying to mimick an application that sends octet streams to and from a server. The data contained in the body looks like raw bytes, and I'm fairly certain the data being sent for each command is static, so I'm hoping to map the bytes to something more readable in my application. For example, I'll have an array that does: `"test" => "&^D^^&@*#dgkel"` So I can call "test" and get the real bytes that need to be sent. Trouble is, PHP seems to convert these bytes. I'm not sure if it is an encoding problem or what, but what has been happing is I'll give it some bytes (for example, `�ھ����@�qs��������������������X����������������������������`) which has a length of 67 I believe, but PHP will say (when I do a var_dump of the HTTP request) that the headers sent contained "Content-Length: 174" or something close to that and the bytes will look like `ï¿½Ú¾ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½@ï¿½qsï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`

So I'm not really sure how to fix this.. Anyone have any ideas? Cheers!

Edit, a little PHP:

```
$request = new HttpRequest($this->GetMessageURL(), HTTP_METH_POST);
$request->addHeaders($headers);
$request->addRawPostData($buttonMapping[$button]);
$request->send();
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can share?  Yeah, sounds like an encoding problem to me, too.  Without seeing any details, I'd suggest thinking about base64 encoding / decoding to avoid the problem....

Comment: Strings in PHP are always encoded with the encoding of the script file. In your case it seems that you’ve inserted this binary data into a file with Unicode encoding (maybe UTF-8) and your editor did the encoding conversion when pasting the binary data. Inerting the binary data in a different format (e.g. hexadecimal escape sequence `"\xhh"`) should work here.

Comment: I'll add the code, but it won't help. As for the base64 encoding, should I encode it before adding it to my application and decode when I send it, or should I actually send the data as base64 encoded data and send a header to tell the server it's encoded. Would the server decode it by default if that header is present?

Comment: @Gumbo, How should I add that hexadecimal escape sequence.. Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: @Gumbo, Oh I see what you mean.. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @iLoch Send the binary data though something like `xxd` and `sed`: `sed '1,/^$/d' http_request.bin | xxd -ps | sed 's/../\\x\0/g'`